# FluentAssertion, check constraint just for condition

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

Inside a c# test I'm asserting with FluentAssertion. But, in this test, the "assert" only should be executed under a condition (when result is not valid)

This is my actual code:

```cs
if (!result.IsValid)
{
    result
        .Errors
        .Should()
        .Contain(e => e.ErrorMessage == MYERROR);
}
```

In my opinion, this code looks ugly, and I would like to rewrite in a more elegant way, something like this:

```cs
// -- DON'T COPY PASTE THIS CODE, IT DON'T COMPILE -- //
result
    .Errors
    .Should()
    .When(!result.IsValid) //<-- something like this
    .Contain(e => e.ErrorMessage == MYERROR);
// -- DON'T COPY PASTE THIS CODE, IT DON'T COMPILE -- //
```

*Notice, in my sample, `result` is a [FluentValidation's ValidationResult](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/main/src/FluentValidation/Results/ValidationResult.cs)*

What would be the right syntax for this code. Maybe, this is an XY problem, and I'm focused on the wrong side of the issue.

The full test:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData("hola", true, "Its ok", null)]
[InlineData("hola\tadeu", false, "Not ok, contains a tab (no printable char)", MYERROR)]
public void OnlyPrintableCharsTest(string name, bool expected, string because, string? errorMsg)
{
    // -- ARRANGE --
    var persona =
        new
        Persona() { Name = nom };

    // -- ACT --

    var result =
        MyCustomOnlyPrintableCharsValidator
        .Validate(persona);

    // -- ASSERT --
    result
        .IsValid
        .Should()
        .Be(expected, because);

    if (!result.IsValid) // <-- Ugly code
    {
        result
            .Errors
            .Should()
            .Contain(e => e.ErrorMessage == errMsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `result.Errors.Should().ContainIf(!result.IsValid, e => e.ErrorMessage == errMsg);` ? Should be possible to make an Extension Method for that, shouldn't it?

Comment: `ContainIf` is not out-of-the-box solution, but, as you say, it is easy to create the extension method (well documented on fluentAssertion website) It is not generic solution, if you want to apply to `Be` you will need `BeIf` and so on, but looks much better than my code. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a separate test for the positive (true) and negative (false) scenario? From the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#avoid-logic-in-tests) "If logic in your test seems unavoidable, consider splitting the test up into two or more different tests.".

Comment: Of course, @pfx, I already suspected that this was a XY problem. I asked for Y, but you found the X. Are you so kind to post your comment as solution? I will check it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to have a separate test for the positive (true) and negative (false) scenario.

From a unit testing best practices [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#avoid-logic-in-tests) from Microsoft:

> If logic in your test seems unavoidable, consider splitting the test up into two or more different tests.

That also simplifies the `InlineData` setup; the `null` for `errorMsg` in the positive scenario can be discarded.
Maybe you can switch to `[Fact]` tests?

Comment: This is the solution, thanks. But I will keep `InlineData`, one set for IsValid and another set, in a different test, for not IsValid. Awesome.